# Does sqlite3 work with PHP 5.0.x?

Tags: php, sqlite

I need to move a small webapp currently running on PHP 5.3.8 and Apache 2.0, to a server with PHP 5.0.4 on Microsoft-IIS 6.0, which I'm not in a position to update. The application uses a Sqlite 3 database with the sqlite3.dll module. This module is included by default in PHP 5.3.x, but I couldn't find any info about whether is would work in an older version.

Does PHP support said module?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP 5.x changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php), sqlite support's been bundled since 5.0.0 beta 1, back in '03. However, seriously consider updating that old 5.0 to something more recent. There's lots of goodies in 5.2/5.3 that you'll be missing out on.